# Angular Syntax Highlighting in Rubymine

Tags: angularjs, rubymine

I am just working through a RailsCast AngularJS tutorial. Loving angular however RubyMine does not want to highlight the code correctly:

```
@RaffleCtrl =  ($scope)->
  $scope.entries = [
    {name: "Foo"}
    {name: "Bar"}
    {name: "Who"}
  ]

  $scope.addEntry = ->
    $scope.entries.push($scope.newEntry)
    $scope.newEntry = {}


  $scope.drawWinner = ->
    entry = $scope.entries[Math.floor(Math.random()*$scope.entries.length)]
```

The biggest problem here is that `$scope.addEntry` is not highlighted as a function its just plain white text - which will be hard when I start building this out into a larger file.

Also thing such as `$scope.entries.push($scope.newEntry)` I would expect `.push` to be highlighted but it is not.

I have the AngularJS plugin installed, and the RailsCasts code style.

What am I doing wrong?